# XML based rest service in quarkus

Tags: java, xml, rest, soap, quarkus

I need to convert my soap based application into rest based quarkus application.

I need a quarkus rest service to take below request and generate response.

**Request :**

```
<sum>
 <a>5</a>
 <b>5</b>
</sum>
```

**Response :**

```
<result>10</result>
```

Any pointers !!

Comment: I've tried to create a REST Resource with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` and with `quarkus-jaxb` dependency but I'm getting `javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type`. For me it looks like Quarkus is not supporting XML in REST service. If there is a way to get this working I'd be interested too.

For client side I think I'll go with Vert.x web client and marshaling/unmarshaling xml with JAXB.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `quarkus-resteasy-jaxb` and `quarkus-resteasy` dependency in your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jaxb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then create a simple model class, but remember the `@XmlRootElement` annotation:

```java
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Fruit {

    public Fruit() {
    }

    public Fruit(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String name;

    public String description;

}
```

And then expose the model via a REST service:

```java
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.Fruit;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/fruit")
public class FruitRestController {

    @GET
    @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Fruit> getFruit() {
        List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<>();
        fruitList.add(new Fruit("Apple", "Crunchy fruit"));
        fruitList.add(new Fruit("Kiwi", "Delicious fruit"));

        return fruitList;
    }
}
```

Now as long as you set the `Accepts application/xml` header this Quarkus rest controller will return a XML response like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<collection>
  <fruit>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <description>Crunchy fruit</description>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>Kiwi</name>
    <description>Delicious fruit</description>
  </fruit>
</collection>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a soap library (e.g [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)) and parse the XML. There will be no particular Quarkus integration, and you will probably have a hard time producing a native image.

Comment: I don't want a soap service. I need a rest service which accept XML and parse it into jave objects using Jackson. I did it in springboot, but Jackson is not supporting in quarkus.

Comment: Jackson is an integrated component in Quarkus: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json#jackson.

Comment: I need a quarkus rest service to take below request and generate response

Request : 
<sum>
     <a>5</a>
     <b>5</b>
</sum>

Response : 
<result>10</result>

Comment: question has been updated. I want to understand how I can accept a xml request and parse it into java object.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jaxb</artifactId>
      <version>1.13.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-mutiny</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

They will make it possible for you to return Uni<> in XML.